# nlohmann : Write json to a TCP socket (and also receive)

Tags: c++, json

I have to convert JSON to raw data and then write it to a file. I found the following sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{

    json j = "{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }"_json;

    std::cout << j.dump() << std::endl;

    //convert json to string 
    std::string s = j.dump ();  
    //convert from string to stream 
    const char *pData = s.c_str();  

    //convert from stream to string
    std::string out(pData );
}
```

Still do not know how to do the opposite direction.

Comment: When the question is about a compiler error you should include the compiler error in the question. And if you post code written by someone else you should provide a reference to the source

Comment: And please try to focus on one quesiton. Title asks how to convert to raw data, but that seems to be done already

Comment: What do you mean by *raw data*? `j.dump()` returns a string. Is that what you want to save to the file? Personally I wouldn't call a string raw data but maybe you are thinking differently.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "raw data"? Do you mean the serialised string? Do you want the raw value of "pi" to be dumped?

Comment: @john Beat me to it by 13s 

Comment: @SimonC Unfortunately past experience tells me that we'll not get any answer, even with two people asking.

Comment: Probably not, no. But without that information, there's no way of helping OP

Comment: @Zvi why do you have `fwrite(j.dump, ...` instead of `fwrite(j.dump(), ...`?

Comment: @k314159  missing parentheses probably seems to be the cause of compilation error

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#tofrom-streams-eg-files-string-streams)?

Comment: Why `fopen`? What was wrong with [std::ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)

Comment: std::string s = j.dump ();

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use fstream instead? Then it [just works](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:43,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:43,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:43,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:43,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfstream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cnlohmann/json.hpp%3E%0A%0Ausing+json+%3D+nlohmann::json%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+file+%3D+std::ofstream%7B%22dump.bin%22%7D%3B%0A++++auto+j+%3D+%22%7B+%5C%22happy%5C%22:+true,+%5C%22pi%5C%22:+3.141+%7D%22_json%3B%0A++++file+%3C%3C+j%3B%0A++++//+File+closes+automatically+at+end+of+scope%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.65570792389582,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27177%27),(name:nlohmann_json,ver:trunk)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:23.838142120009067,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:21.506149956095136,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    auto file = std::ofstream{"dump.bin"};
    auto j = "{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }"_json;
    file << j;
    // File closes automatically at end of scope
}
```